Error in Angular 17 SSR (Reflect.getMetadata is not a function)
I get "Reflect.getMetadata is not a function" error when trying so serve Angular 17 with SSR after adding class with @Type() decorator from "class-transformer".
I've tried to import 'reflect-metadata' before main code and add "reflect-metadata" in polyfills, but it doesn't work.
How to reproduce this error:

ng new --ssr
npm i class-transformer
Add code

@Type(() => Date) date: Date; 

to the main component.
If you have any ideas how to fix it, please let me know.
Thank you.

add "/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js" to angular.json
architect.build.options.scripts
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/x",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"
            ]
          },

